# Trouble understanding when to use $\operatorname{Var}(aX) = a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

From SOA Sample #203

> A machine has two components and fails when both components fail. The number of
>   years from now until the first component fails, X, and the number of years from now until
>   the machine fails, Y, are random variables with joint density function
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac1{18}e^{-(x+y)\over6}&\text{if }0<x<y\\
> 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X=2)$.

To begin one must calculate $f_{Y|X}(y|2)$. I eventually get

$$ {{{1\over18}e^{-(2+y)\over6}}\over{{1\over3}e^{-{4\over 6}}}}={{1\over6}e^{2-y\over6}}$$

At this point I can factor out the $e^{2\over6}$ and will be left with the exponential distribution times a constant:

$$e^{2\over6}{{1\over6}e^{-y\over6}}$$

I thought that one should apply the rule $\operatorname{Var}(aX) = a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$ here.

$$\operatorname{Var}(e^{2\over6}Y)=e^{4\over6}\operatorname{Var}(Y)=e^{4\over6}\cdot36$$

However the true solution is $36$. Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not "exponential distribution times a constant", it is a shifted exponential distribution.  Note that your formula for the conditional density is only valid for $y > 2$.  Thus the conditional distribution for $Y$ given $X = 2$ is the distribution of $2 + T$ where $T$ is exponential with rate $1/6$.  The variance of $2+T$ is the same as the variance of $T$.